# Print 'O' with odd id and 'E' with even id in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to write an SQL query for the following:

Input:

```
Id | Name    
-- | ----   
1  | A  
2  | B  
3  | C
```

Output:

```
Id | Name | IdType    
-- | ---- | -----   
1  | A    | O  
2  | B    | E  
3  | C    | O
```

I can extract odd or even rows by putting where condition `Id % 2 = 0`. But I'm not sure how to put 'O' or 'E' in the new column.

Comment: do you want to update your table?

Comment: No updation required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, using the [`IF()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT Id, Name, IF(Id % 2 = 0, 'E', 'O') AS IdType FROM table_name;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is no mention of using the row number in the question, only the ID. OP even mentions the condition `Id % 2 = 0` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You make use of `CASE` and print `E` when `Id%2=0` and `O` if `Id%2` is not equal to `0`

```
SELECT Id,Name,
CASE WHEN (Id%2)=0 THEN 'E'
     ELSE 'O' END AS IdType
FROM [YourTable]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use this query If you want to update your table

```
    UPDATE table_name SET IdType = CASE 
    WHEN mod (Id, 2) = 0 THEN 'E'
    WHEN mod (Id, 2) <> 0 THEN 'O'
    ELSE IdType
    END
```

> If you just want to print,then `Robby Cornelissen` had a perfect answer for you